# How to effectively store chat logs [NodeJS, SQL]

Tags: node.js, logging, history

I'm trying to make a social media service (in nodeJS) where people have different groups and inside those groups there are different channels where people can talk/chat. I want to log all of it/keep it stored so people can see the history. I got stuck when deciding where/how to store everything/the logs. Should i keep everything in a text file inside different file or store it in a database (and if so relational or non)? Im going for a clean and fast solution(when I say fast I mean it can store it quickly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that's what databseses are for. Fast and effecient. How about postgresql? A group "has_many" users and "has_many" logs. Using that relation you gain a lot of power with respect to searching for logs, either through users or the logs themselves. I personally like relational databases but it is naturally possible to do it without them.

https://node-postgres.com/